# X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID returns CN with number as text

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

When I issue the following command:

```
cn[(sizeof cn) - 1] = 0;
if (X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(subj_p, NID_commonName,
                              cn, (sizeof cn) - 1) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Subject has no CN\n");
    return -1;
}
if (strncasecmp(cn, options.server_p, sizeof cn) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Subject CN mismatch (%s != %s)\n",
            options.server_p, cn);
    return -1;
}
```

Where `options.server_p` is `a1.accessmylan.com`

I get the following error:

```
Subject CN mismatch (b1.accessmylan.com != BONE.ACCESSMYLAN.COM)
```

And if I try with a different server I get:

```
Subject CN mismatch (a1.accessmylan.com != aone.ACCESSMYLAN.COM)
```

Does anybody know why this might happen and / or how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to set the `options.server_p` to a name that matches the cert, or change your validation check to be more flexible, or change the cert to accept alternate spellings, and your validation code to check against the alternate names in addition to the common name.

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown the error, both the common name are really different. They are not same in any sense.

As per my knowledge common names **b1.accessmylan.com** and **BONE.ACCESSMYLAN.COM** are different in reality.

Please check your certificate and its common name and input too.

In your code

> `cn[(sizeof cn) - 1] = 0;`

you are using sizeof to count the number of elements of cn. sizeof operator gives the number of bytes, not number of elements.

Correct way to do this (if cn is declared as a static array in the scope)

```
cn[sizeof(cn)/sizeof(cn[0]) - 1] = 0;
```

This might be one of the issue but not necessarily this one.

Another thing is that in your code, in strcasecmp, you are passing the size of cn. As a good practice, you should pass length of cn or options.server_p whichever is smaller.